# What does "a" mean at the end of a refrigerant's designation (R-134a)?

Tags: chemical-engineering, refrigeration

I was studying the designation of names to refrigerants.

The following is the basic formula:

R - (m - 1) ( n + 1) ( o )

where:
m = number of carbon atoms in the refrigerant
n = number of hydrogen atoms in the refrigerant
o = number of fluorine atoms in the refrigerant

So R-134a has:

1 + 1 = 2 carbon atoms
3 - 1 = 2 hydrogen atoms
4 fluorine atoms

**What does the 'a' at the end mean?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> R134a..Here "a" is used to denote that it is an isomer. R134 and R134a have same chemical formula and atomic weight but different chemical structures.
>
> R134 has NBP of  about -19 C whereas R134a has a NBP of about -26C.
>
> And dont use capital 'A' in R134a …. "A" denotes that the refrigerant is non -azeotropic.

[ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_does_A_in_R-134_A_refrigerant_stand_for)

Comment: *same chemical formula and atomic weight but different chemical structures* so does this affect the properties of the refrigerant ?
I mean are thermal properties of R134 and R134a different?

Comment: @Fennekin Correct. "R134" is not useful as a refrigerant due to its molecular properties. A similar trend appears in pharmaceuticals with different isomers of a drug.

Answer (score 2):

If a refrigerant contains 'a' at its end it is the isomer of that refrigerant.
Example 'R123' is 'C2H2F3Cl2' and 'R123a' is the isomer of the same molecule.